# Mac OS X Server - UPS battery level stuck at 0% despite fully charged

Tags: mac-osx, ups

I am running a Mac OS X Server 10.5.8 and have a APC Smart-UPS 1500 connected to the Mac via USB. My Mac server correctly sees that the UPS is connected but fails to read the correct battery level of the UPS.

I have tried everything I can think of to get this to work. This includes rebooting both devices and re-plugging each other in but to no avail.

Below is what shows in the energy saver menu.

[image: Mac server not showing correct battery level]

Anyone know how to get my Mac Server to report the correct battery level?

Comment: This sounds like the UPS is not reporting battery capacity correctly -- Have you contacted APC to troubleshoot? What did they tell you?

Comment: Is the ups by chance a SmartUPS SC 1500? (they have SC on the front label, so easily identifiable).

Comment: @Shaun There is no mention of SC anywhere on the unit. On the front is clearly labelled: APC SmartUPS 1500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time I asked and couldn't find an answer I just accepted that it would never display properly. Well looked today and if by magic the system is now reporting the battery level correctly. So its fixed itself some time between now and then.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a whole lot that "administrators" can do with this sort of thing.   You should probably contact APC, or, if you can find a local battery, try replacing it and see what happens.